# Error: Unable to install any program through Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: bash, software-center

No matter the program, I get an Error: `The file "home/..." could not be opened.`

I was able to install VMware using `gksudo bash` command; however it does not work with any other programs.

I have also tried `sudo apt-get install`

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt4-webkit:i386 python-commandnotfound python-gdbm
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 325 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main software-center all 13.10-0ubuntu4.1 [325 kB]
Fetched 325 kB in 6s (49.6 kB/s)                                               
(Reading database ... 203377 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../software-center_13.10-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) over (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
Software catalog update was successful.
jakezeal@jakezeal-P35V3:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       
Ign http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [64.4 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages         
Get:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [245 kB]        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_CA                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en       
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [5,359 B] 
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en       
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [143 kB]    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en         
Get:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [5,133 B] 
Get:6 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [653 kB] 
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [15.9 kB]
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [327 kB]
Get:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.0 kB]
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [631 kB] 
Get:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [15.6 kB]
Get:12 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [328 kB]
Get:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [13.1 kB]
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                           
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                       
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_CA                 
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_CA             
Hit http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_CA           
Ign http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_CA           
Fetched 2,461 kB in 57s (42.6 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
```

I am running the latest version of Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS as the only OS on my SSD harddrive. Additionally, I have updated everything through `sudo apt-get update`

Additionally, I tried reinstalling the Software Center.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: "Error: The file "home/..." could not be opened."

Comment: And nothing else? Or some file name is also there?

Comment: Please give output of `sudo apt-get update`. Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, the /... refers to username & filename.

Comment: So what is the EXACT error message?

Comment: In the software center it is: Error: The file "/home/jakezeal/Anaconda2-2.4.0--Linux-x86_64.sh"

Comment: The output of sudo apt-get update is too long for me to add; there are no errors though.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output there. And what do you try to do with the Software Center? Open the script with it or what?

Comment: Yes, I simply try to open the downloaded file with Ubuntu Software Center. As is perhaps obvious, I am new to Ubuntu, is this not the way to proceed with an installation?

Comment: That is wrong. You do not open `bash` scripts with USC. Everything is OK with the USC.

Comment: So how do I install this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run bash scripts by Ubuntu Software Center.

You can run this script in terminal by running:

```
sh /home/jakezeal/Anaconda2-2.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

or just

```
./Anaconda2-2.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

if your current directory is `/home/jakezeal`.

Comment: The output is:
`
bash: ./Anaconda2-2.4.0--Linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: There was a spelling mistake. Wow so in the future, I simply type `./` before the file I would like to install ?

Comment: Correct if the file is in your Home directory.

Comment: The file name was:
`./Anaconda2-2.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` (you added a dash)